# How can I pass parameters to a modal in Ionic?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, parameters

I've been trying to pass a parameter through a modal where I'm trying make an "individual page" for each "item" I have.

Foreach item:
...

```
 <button (click)="viewIndividualTour(item)" ion-fab class="fab-map">
        <ion-icon name='information-circle'></ion-icon>
 </button>
```

I created the viewIndividualTour function in typescript and it's like this:

```
viewIndividualTour(item) {
    let viewTourModal = this.modalCtrl.create(ViewTour, item});
    viewTourModal.present();
  }
```

So i'm trying to pass "item" to the ViewTour page. To be able to use "item" in my ViewTour template html page, I would need to define it in .ts first. How can I do that?

**Some background:** When listing all the items: 
 `<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let item of items; let idx = index;">`...
and then I can use `item.cartegory` for instance.

In the .ts for that page, I defined items as: `public items: any;`

And I filled "items" with all the data by running this function:

```
refreshTours() {
    this.db.getDocumentClient().query({
      ...linesOfCode...
    }).promise().then((data) => {
      this.items = data.Items;
   ...linesofCode...
  }
```

So there I defined items. In my new case, I want to create an individual modal for an item instead of listing them all with ngFor (foreach).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the main page you pass an object with all params as second parameter to the create() method, just as you already did:

```
viewIndividualTour( item ) {
  let viewTourModal = this.modalCtrl.create( ViewTour,{ item: item} );
  viewTourModal.present();
}
```

In the typescript file of your modal (ViewTour.ts) you can use NavParams to access the given object:

```
item : any;

constructor( navParams: NavParams ) {
   this.item = navParams.get( 'item' );
}
```

With this you have an item member variable which you can use in your template.